# Generating range of unique random numbers for each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to create a range of unique random numbers between 0 to 99999 for each group.
I have following dataset

```
District    Prefix  Quota       
A           98426   783
A           98427   223
A           98446   127
A           98626   51
B           98049   167
B           98079   153
B           98140   120
B           98159   139
B           98169   182
B           98249   86
B           98426   588
B           98446   96
C           98049   104
C           98060   68
C           98149   65
C           98150   68
C           98159   86
C           98160   80
C           98169   113
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 98426, 783],
    ['A', 98427, 223],
    ['A', 98446, 127],
    ['A', 98626, 51],
    ['B', 98049, 167],
    ['B', 98079, 153],
    ['B', 98140, 120],
    ['B', 98159, 139],
    ['B', 98169, 182],
    ['B', 98249, 86],
    ['B', 98426, 588],
    ['B', 98446, 96],
    ['C', 98049, 104],
    ['C', 98060, 68],
    ['C', 98149, 65],
    ['C', 98150, 68],
    ['C', 98159, 86],
    ['C', 98160, 80],
    ['C', 98169, 113]
], 
    columns=['District', 'Prefix', 'Quota'])
```

so I have to generate "quota" number of unique number from 0 to 99999 and add it to prefix so I can create a 10 digit number.

I tried:

```
numbers = np.random.choice(range(99999), size=df.Quota.sum(), replace=False)
random = df.Prefix.repeat(df.Quota)*100000 + numbers
```

but the problem is, it subtotals "Quota" and generates the unique numbers from 0 to 99999. but I want unique number 0 to 99999 available for each prefix. for example. suppose np.random.choice(range(99999), size=df.Quota.sum(), replace=False) generated 16195 and add to the first prefix "98426". the same number wont be generated and it wont be available to other prefix. so the range (0-99999) should be unique for each prefix

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question. You have a quota column in your dataframe - do you want to create a new one? Also - didn't understand the issue you described in the last paragraph. Perhaps you should provide sample output.

Comment: there is prefix column and quota column, ignore the district column. 

in the first row the prefix is 98426 and the quota is given 783. now I have to generate 783 unique random numbers between (0 to 99999) and add it to 98426. 

now again in the second row the prefix is 98427 and quota is 223. now again I have to generate 223 random numbers between 0 to 99999 and the generated numbers can contain numbers from first 783.

Comment: the code I tried generated unique numbers for all the prefix (the sum of quota column). but I want to groupby prefix column and generate numbers among them @Roy2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `transform`, `random.choice`, and `explode`.

```
def make_random_numbers(x):
    total = x.sum()
    r = np.random.choice(range(99999), total, replace = False)
    chunks = x.cumsum()[:-1]
    res =  np.hsplit(r, chunks)  
    return res

df["rand_items"] = df.groupby("Prefix")["Quota"].transform(make_random_numbers)
df.explode("rand_items")
```

The result is:

```
  District  Prefix  Quota rand_items
0        A   98426    783       2681
0        A   98426    783      94952
0        A   98426    783      79496
0        A   98426    783      58361
0        A   98426    783      54883
0        A   98426    783      44819
0        A   98426    783      36209
0        A   98426    783      91710
...
18        C   98169    113      41859
18        C   98169    113      92311
18        C   98169    113      18572
18        C   98169    113      72492
18        C   98169    113      39188
18        C   98169    113      36808
18        C   98169    113      32055
18        C   98169    113      74678
```

Comment: It only generated 1 random number for each prefix. .I want 167  unique number for first prefix. so the total number of rows will be total of Quota column i.e. 3299 . and in a different dataset

Comment: Prefix 98049 has two different quotas - which one is right?  167 or 104? or should I generate two random sets of these two sizes?

Comment: can we create unique 167+104 for duplicate prefix 'quota'.

Comment: Ah. just saw your last comment. I'm generating two sets of unique numbers in my solution - the first of 167, the second of 104. It can be changed if needed.

Comment: why do I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode' error?

Comment: emm. are you using your dataframe and then my code exactly?

Comment: Here's the documentation of 'explode': https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html. What version of pandas are you using? this is really strange.

Comment: Great. Do you mind accepting my answer for future generations?

Comment: thank you for the solution but I have last issue though. .the randomly generated number gives duplicates within prefix if the numbers on prefix column has duplicates. .can we add the quota of duplicates prefix and generate random numbers from that?. .just like you said 98049 has two quotas 167 and 104.. can we add 167+104=271 and generated 271 random numbers?

Comment: Edited the code to prevent overlap between two rows with the same prefix.

Comment: I do. If you have two rows with the same prefix, you want no overlap between their random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns a list of random choices for each row:

```
def gen_rand(x):
    return (x['Prefix'].min() * 1E5 + np.random.choice(range(99999),
        size=sum(x['Quota']), replace = False)).astype(int)
df.groupby('Prefix').apply(gen_rand)
```